# How to disable the Windows Consumer Experience in Windows 10 (1909)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy, windows-10-v1909

**In previous Windows-10-Versions it was possible to disable the Windows-Consumer-Experience via GPO.**

- Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Cloud Content --> "Turn off Microsoft consumer experience"

**Or** with the RegistryEntry:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent
  Change the Dword "DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures" to 1

Now, I can't find either of them options anymore.
Where are they now?

Comment: The options in group policy editor are there for me, using 1909.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to alter a number of privacy settings, such as the [Windows *Customer Experience Improvement Program*](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-opt-out-customer-experience-improvement-program-windows-10) [**not "consumer experience"**], as well as numerous other infringements on privacy such as *Inventory Collector* and multiple types of telemetry, is to use a third-party tool, e.g. [O&O ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/shutup10/).

Many of these tools also remember *your* settings, and, after Windows update resumes telemetry usw, can put the settings back to *your* preferences.

[image: ShutUp10 Privacy Settings]

Comment: Very very good! thank you!